# Basic pytest teardown that runs on test completion

Tags: pytest, fixtures, teardown

I am minimally using pytest as a generic test runner for large automated integration tests against various API products at work, and I've been trying to find an equally generic example of a teardown function that runs on completion of any test, regardless of success or failure.

My typical use pattern is super linear and usually goes something like this:

```
def test_1():
    <logic>
    assert something

def test_2():
    <logic>
    assert something

def test_3():
    <logic>
    assert something
```

Occasionally, when it makes sense to do so, at the top of my script I toss in a setup fixture with an autouse argument set to "True" that runs on the launch of every script:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_something():
    testhelper = TestHelper
    testhelper.create_something(host="somehost", channel="somechannel")

def test_1():
    <logic>
    assert something

def test_2():
    <logic>
    assert something

def test_3():
    <logic>
    assert something
```

Up until recently, disposable docker environments have allowed me to get away with skipping the entire teardown process, but I'm in a bit of pinch where one of those is not available right now. Ideally, without diverting from the same linear pattern I've already been using, how would I implement another pytest fixture that does something like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def teardown():
    testhelper = TestHelper
    testhelper.delete_something(thing=something)
```

when the run is completed?

Answer (score 6):

Every fixture may have a tear down part:

```
@pytest.fixture
def something(request):
   # setup code
   def finalize():
       # teardown code
   request.addfinalizer(finalize)
   return fixture_result
```

Or as I usually use it:

```
@pytest.fixture
def something():
    # setup code
    yield fixture_result
    # teardown code
```

Note that in pytest pre-3.0, the decorator required for the latter idiom was `@pytest.yield_fixture`. Since 3.0, however, one can just use the regular `@pytest.fixture` decorator, and `@pytest.yield_fixture` is [deprecated](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/yieldfixture.html).

See more [here](http://pytest.org/latest/yieldfixture.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use these functions in your `conftest.py`

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    pass    

def pytest_runtest_teardown(item):
    pass
```

see [here](http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/plugins.html#generic-runtest-hooks) for docs

Comment: it's not clear to me what 'item' is here.  can you provide an example?  what if i just want to remove a file?